# CSS Button turn to normal size smoothly when un-hovered

Tags: html, css

im new to css and i don't have any idea how to make button get smaller smoothly when user unhovered the button , i have successfully make the button get bigger smoothly but it turn into normal size in instant time , this is my code :

```html
<html>

<head>

<style>
body {
background-image:url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/webtreats/assets/posts/976/full/tileable-light-blurs-and-abstract-circles-18.png");
}
.title {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
border : 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
background-color:rgba(0, 199, 255, 0.7);
font-size:100%;
color:white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.firstcontainer {
position:relative;
margin-top:3%;
}
.menubutton {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
font-size:200%;
margin-left:1%;
text-align:center;
background-color: rgba(0,157,255,0.5);
display:inline-block;
color:white;
border:3px solid white;
padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
}
.menubutton:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,199,255,0.5);
padding: 1.1% 1.1% 1.1% 1.1%;
transition-duration:0.5s;
}
.menutext {
color:white;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="title"> <h1 > English Lesson </h1> </div>
<div class="firstcontainer">

<div class="menubar"></div>

<a href="#" class="menutext"><div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Home</u></i></strong></div></a>
<a href="#" clas="menutext"><div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Contacts</u></i></strong></div></a>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**I am sorry if this already asked somewhere but i cannot find it at search engine such as google .**

Is there any way to make something like `.menubutton:unhover` ?

Comment: `.menubutton:unhover` is the same as `.menubutton`

Comment: @Banzay without duration

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: BTW if `padding` or `margin` has all 4 values are equal, you can put the only one: `padding:1%;` instead of `padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;`

Comment: @Banzay thanks ! i didnt know

Comment: guys i will upvote all answer aftrer i reach 15 reputation ok ? :)

Comment: @Banzay .menubutton is NOT the same as .menubutton:unhover. The rules you give to ..menubutton will be applied to .menubutton:hover unless overwritten.

Comment: @LajosArpad which of them of `selector:unhover` would not be applied to `selector`???

Comment: @Banzay you misunderstood me. If you add a rule to selector, then it will be applied to selector:hover as well, therefore selector rule applies even if the tag is in a hovered state, so selector is more general and therefore is NOT the same as selector:unhover.

Comment: do you mean: `selector:not(:hover)`?

Comment: @Banzay, that's right.

Comment: @LajosArpad  I can't believe but just now I used such kind of selector and nothing  else siuted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41493512/4206079

Comment: @Banzay :hover means that the selector is applied and the tag is being hovered. A selector without :hover means that the selector is applied, which is totally independent from hover state. Try it out. Add an arbitrary style to a .foo class and see whether that style cease from being applied if you hover a tag having that class. You will see that hover will not remove that style, so a selector without the :hover does not mean it will be applied only if not hovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add transition to `menubutton` also,  the transition property gets applied to the hover state, therefore your animation takes 0.5 second when changing to that specific state. Adding it to the regular state will also apply it when changing back from a special state

```css
body {
 background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/webtreats/assets/posts/976/full/tileable-light-blurs-and-abstract-circles-18.png");
}
.title {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 border : 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 background-color: rgba(0, 199, 255, 0.7);
 font-size: 100%;
 color: white;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.firstcontainer {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 3%;
}
.menubutton {
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
 font-size: 200%;
 margin-left: 1%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,157,255,0.5);
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 border: 3px solid white;
 padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.menubutton:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,199,255,0.5);
 padding: 1.1% 1.1% 1.1% 1.1%;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.menutext {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1 > English Lesson </h1>
</div>
<div class="firstcontainer">
  <div class="menubar"></div>
  <a href="#" class="menutext">
  <div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Home</u></i></strong></div>
  </a> <a href="#" clas="menutext">
  <div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Contacts</u></i></strong></div>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ! its work :) i will upvote for extra reputation if you can explain " how that work "

Comment: Easy explanation: the transition property gets applied to the hover state, therefore your animation takes 0.5 second when changing *to that specific state*. Adding it to the regular state will also apply it when *changing back from a special state*.

Comment: edit your answer into that so other people can know too :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `transition` property needs to be on the default `.menubutton` class. This means that when you hover the button it will transition to the new style and then back to the default again when you stop hovering.

```
.menubutton {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  font-size:200%;
  margin-left:1%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: rgba(0,157,255,0.5);
  display:inline-block;
  color:white;
  border:3px solid white;
  padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
}
.menubutton:hover {
  background-color:rgba(0,199,255,0.5);
  padding: 1.1% 1.1% 1.1% 1.1%;
}
```

The reason that your animation doesn't work when you stop hovering is that the `transition` property is no longer applied to the element, as it only exists on hover.

Comment: thanks for explanation :) i will upvote this but still sorry i already have answer that i will mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use - in cases where it's possible - `transform` property. It handles the animations very smoothly.

In your case, I suggest you to use `transform: scale()` instead, animation works fine and it looks even better than before.

By the way, if you want to apply a value, e.g. `5px` to padding or margin, you don't have to write it separately for all directions, just use simply:

`margin: 5px` or `padding: 5px`. It will affect top, bottom, left and right directions together.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/webtreats/assets/posts/976/full/tileable-light-blurs-and-abstract-circles-18.png");
}
.title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  background-color: rgba(0, 199, 255, 0.7);
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.firstcontainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
.menubutton {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 157, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.menubutton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 199, 255, 0.5);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.menutext {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1> English Lesson </h1> 
</div>
<div class="firstcontainer">

  <div class="menubar"></div>

  <a href="#" class="menutext">
    <div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Home</u></i></strong>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" clas="menutext">
    <div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Contacts</u></i></strong>
    </div>
  </a>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to class

```
.menubutton {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
font-size:200%;
margin-left:1%;
text-align:center;
background-color: rgba(0,157,255,0.5);
display:inline-block;
color:white;
border:3px solid white;
padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: thanks ! :) u help me understand better , but sorry i will just upvote because first answer already give the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scale()` effect and apply `transition-duraion` for both unhovered and hovered button

Look at snippet:

```css
body {
background-image:url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/webtreats/assets/posts/976/full/tileable-light-blurs-and-abstract-circles-18.png");
}
.title {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
border : 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
background-color:rgba(0, 199, 255, 0.7);
font-size:100%;
color:white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.firstcontainer {
position:relative;
margin-top:3%;
}
.menubutton {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
font-size:200%;
margin-left:1%;
text-align:center;
background-color: rgba(0,157,255,0.5);
display:inline-block;
color:white;
border:3px solid white;
padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.menubutton:hover {
transform: scale(1.2);
transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.menutext {
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"> <h1 > English Lesson </h1> </div>
<div class="firstcontainer">

<div class="menubar"></div>

<a href="#" class="menutext"><div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Home</u></i></strong></div></a>
<a href="#" clas="menutext"><div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Contacts</u></i></strong></div></a>


</div>
```

Comment: thanks for telling me about scale() :) ( which i cant found it at my tutorial ) , i will upvote this but sorry i have answer that answered first before you so i will not mark this as answer , just upvote

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>

<style>
body {
background-image:url("http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/webtreats/assets/posts/976/full/tileable-light-blurs-and-abstract-circles-18.png");
}
.title {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
border : 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
background-color:rgba(0, 199, 255, 0.7);
font-size:100%;
color:white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.firstcontainer {
position:relative;
margin-top:3%;
}
.menubutton {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
font-size:200%;
margin-left:1%;
text-align:center;
background-color: rgba(0,157,255,0.5);
display:inline-block;
color:white;
border:3px solid white;
padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
transition: padding 0.1s;
}
.menubutton:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,199,255,0.5);
padding: 1.1% 1.1% 1.1% 1.1%;
}
.menutext {
color:white;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="title"> <h1 > English Lesson </h1> </div>
<div class="firstcontainer">

<div class="menubar"></div>

<a href="#" class="menutext"><div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Home</u></i></strong></div></a>
<a href="#" clas="menutext"><div class="menubutton"><strong><i><u>Contacts</u></i></strong></div></a>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Just remove **transition-duration** from hover element and add a **transition: padding 0.1s** to the button class. The animation does not look so smooth due to small padding change.

Comment: wow ! cant believe you can use padding as value ! :) thanks i will upvote this , but as you read all my previous comment , i already have answer to get mark as answer