# CSS Reverse transition and select previous sibling

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, siblings

Bootstrap container has two forms horizontally.
Hovering over Form1 will increase the width and decreases the width of form2.
but reverse is not happening. Any suggestions please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  #row{
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-style: groove;
  }

  #form1{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.75s ease;
  }

  #form1:hover{  
    width: 75%;
  }

  #form1:hover + #form2{
     width: 25%
   }

  #form2{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.75s ease;
  }  

  #form2:hover{
  width: 75%;  
  }

  #form2:hover ~ #form1{
     width: 25%
     }
  </style>


</head>
<body>

<div  class="container" >

  <div id="row" class="row" >
    <div id="form1" class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- form1 -->
        <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
    <div id="form2" class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- form 2 -->
        <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please see the below image. When hovering on Green form, form goes left to right ,Orange form decreases the width and Green form increases the width but this is not happening while hovering on Orange form(Reverse direction).**

[image]

Basically I'm trying to achieve form like [THIS](https://site.uplabs.com/posts/sign-in-and-sign-out)

Comment: CSS can only select siblings coming after not before the one you specify. In other words, it can't look back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `flexbox`. As Selva has mentioned, CSS can only select the next sibling, not the previous. However, with flexbox this is much easier:

```
.flexible{display: flex; flex-direction: row;}
#form1:hover{  
    width: 100%;
}
#form2:hover{  
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2g4krj0f/

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, I'm very new to CSS, so for working good, need to learn about flex :) . Basically I'm trying to achieve as in the link :  https://site.uplabs.com/posts/sign-in-and-sign-out

Comment: If I hover on any form the other form should reduce 
the width to 10% - 20%, in that width I'll show only Sign In/Sign Up icon. How can I achieve this.

Comment: great job, I was struggling in searching dynamic page in google. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution with pure CSS exists. You need to define css-rule for selector which selects form1 when this form is unhovered while row is hovered: `#row:hover > #form1:not(:hover)`

```css
#row:hover > #form1:not(:hover){
     width: 25%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/0Q2gFDoc4y

look at snippet (for some reason it works in full screen mode):

```css
#row{
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-style: groove;
  }

  #form1{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.75s ease;
  }

  #form1:hover{  
    width: 75%;
  }

  #form1:hover + #form2{
     width: 25%
   }

  #form2{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 0.75s ease;
  }  

  #form2:hover{
  width: 75%;  
  }

  #row:hover > #form1:not(:hover){
     width: 25%;
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  class="container" >

  <div id="row" class="row" >
    <div id="form1" class="col-xs-6">
    <!-- form1 -->
        <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
    <div id="form2" class="col-xs-6">
    <!-- form 2 -->
        <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked , it is misbehaving when I hover on row and sometimes when I hover on Orange form.